Nginx configuration issue - 404 not found
When i go to the website example.com website is visible, but once i go to the route for ex : example.com/ex/test
it's not accessable.
for ex, if i go to example.com/upload it works fine...
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name ******* www.*******;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.csr.html;

    # Security headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    # Proxy requests to backend for API
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Handle static uploads
    location /uploads {
        alias /root/angular-ssr/src/backend/uploads/;
        autoindex on;
        allow all;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Serve Angular application
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    # Specific handling for routes like /gifs
    location /gifs {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}


Any ideas how can i resolve this issue? or is the issue from nginx and should i find a issue in my angular project?

I think that you can't serve directly the angular app you have to set a reverse proxy as described in this page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-node-angular
You get a 404 because you have configured the server like that, if you can provide server logs or more info.
